# Grails DataBindingListener not hearing binding events

Tags: spring, grails

I added a class in src/groovy that implements the DataBindingListener interface. My init/Application file registers the Spring bean in the doWithSpring method

```
@Override
Closure doWithSpring() {

    def beans = {

        applicationBindingListener(org.mkv.ApplicationBindingListener)
    }
    return beans
}
```

I confirmed the bean is registered. However it doesn't seem to be receiving any of the binding events.

I'm using grails 4.0.0

Comment: I think it's a bug in Grails 4 as the `GrailsWebDataBinder` is initialized via `DataBindingConfiguration` but the `setDataBindingListener` is never called. We will soon push the fix for the same. The commit https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/f0ceb146d76461169d8f6937e18f58fde524293d should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I edit config/spring/resources.groovy. It's the source.

```
beans = {
  dataBindingListener org.mkv.ApplicationBindingListener
}
```

And, The code below is added as a test case method to ensure that the bean configured in the test code is used.

```
  boolean loadExternalBeans() {
    true
  }
```